# rom on Xperia E4g instead of E1

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom

Im trying to install lineage os in Xperia E4g E2003 but I can't find It. I want to flash and E1 rom but im not sure if It Is going to work.

Comment: ROMs only work on devices they are designed for. Even devices very similar like a single/dual SIM device can be enough to make it fail if you are using the wrong version. And in your case half the device seems to be different (display, CPU, ...).

Comment: Is there and way i can design a rom myself so i don't have to wait until someone posts One?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but most people are lacking the required skills (including me) for generating a device tree, compiling and modifying a Linux kernel (C/C++) and whole Android system and finally test and debug it to fix all the problems that occur. Even for some-one skilled I would assume developing a ROM from scratch will require minimum 30-100+ hours. With a fast multi-core PC with SSD even compiling a full ROM can take several hours.